# Kubernetes Persistent volume not found start.sh issue

Tags: kubernetes

There is an application in DockerHub and the working directory is `ENTRYPOINT /home/django/start.sh`

I want to add a persistent volume for /home/django foler but when I add it, it can't find start.sh in the logs of the pod. How should I integrate this. I am adding the lines I added to the following kubernetes deployment file.

```
        volumeMounts:
        - name: django-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /home/django/
      volumes:
      - name: django-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: django-pv-claim
```

Logs:

```
Error: failed to create containerd task: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/home/django/start.sh": stat /home/django/start.sh: no such file or directory: unknown
```

This side is not very clear to me. I would like to know exactly what I'm missing. And how can I move the app to persistent volume?

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: if you mount a volume on a folder that is not empty (in the container), the stuff in the folder will not be available (just the same as in basic linux).

Comment: @MarianTheisen Thanks for your comment, It s very helpful :)  I just need to know, how I can process regarding this structure.

Comment: that depends on what you are trying to do. usually you should separate your code (that lies in the container) from persistent storage (where you probably want to store user upload or log files or whatever), and not just "put everything on a pv". create a subfolder, mount the pv there, and use that for your uploads/logs/whatever you want to store persistently.

Comment: docker hub image folder `/home/django/`, I want to persistent that folder. Is it possible ?

Comment: You should not mount a volume over your application code at all.  There's a plain-Docker pattern where this apparently works, but it ignores changes in the underlying image and it's not really a best practice.  Can you keep your data somewhere else?  Ideally, can you keep your data somewhere external to the pod, like a relational database StatefulSet?